# How to re classify 20 newsgroups data set from 20 to 6

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I have downloaded the popular 20 newsgroups data set which has 20 classes, but I want to re-classify the whole documents into six classes since some classes are very related.

So for example, all computer related docs should have a new class say 1. As it is now, the docs are assigned from 1-20 reflecting the classes. The computer related classes are 2,3,4,5,and 6.

I want say, 1 to be the class of all the computer related(2,3,4,5,6). I tested it by using `20_newsgroups.target[0]`, and it gave me 7. Meaning the class of the doc at 0 is 7.

I re-assigned it to a new class using `20_newsgroups.target[0]='1'` and when I try `20_newsgroups.target[0]`, it shows 1 which is OK.

But how can I do this for all the documents that currently have (2,3,4,5,6) as their class? I can easily extend it to other classes if I understand that one.I also try for d in 20_newsgroups:

```
if 20_newsgroups.target in [2,3,4,5,6], 20_newsgroups.target='1'.
```

But this is showing an error that "the truth value of an array with more than one element is unambiguous, use a.any() or a.all".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but you seem to want to join categories into supercategories. This should not be hard to do, but it's less than optimal to do this at a late stage of the experiment. If you want to reduce the number of categories, do this by joining some of the categories as the very first step of your process. That way, similar samples from different (original) categories will not cause confusion in the training phase (provided, of course, that they now belong to the same new category), thereby producing a better overall result.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want to do.Is there any better way of doing it?Thank you

Comment: Better than what I just proposed? Why would I post a subpar answer? Why is this not acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. The code is based on the retrieval of the 20newsgroup data set with scikit learn: https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html

```
topic_1 = [0,15,19]
topic_2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
topic_3 = [6]
topic_4 = [7,8,9,10]
topic_5 = [11,12,13,14]
topic_6 = [16,17,18]
topics = [topic_1, topic_2, topic_3, topic_4, topic_5, topic_6]
```

The topic distribution is based on the table provided by http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/ (but can be adjusted). The following code reduces the amount of categories of the data set.

```
twenty_train_reduced = twenty_train.target.copy
for index, target in enumerate(twenty_train.target):
  for topic_i, topic in enumerate(topics):
    if(target in topic):
      twenty_train_reduced[index] = topic_i
```